# Trying to set up GCM demo application - device registration doesn't work

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

So I've been following Google's tutorial to set up GCM demo apps on an Android emulator (the one here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html). I got the server side working - I have a tomcat server that displays "No devices registered!" on the GCM demo page. I've installed the client-side app on an Android emulator with target Google APIs (trying to get GCM working on one targeted to 4.1 simply spits out "Unfortunately, GCM Demo has stopped" every time I run the application) - the application runs successfully, but it can't connect to the server to register the device (it goes through all 5 attempts). I did edit SERVER_URL, SENDER_ID and api.key to the correct values  (I've followed every step of the tutorial) - what am I missing here? The browser on the emulator also appears to work fine.

Edit: Fixed url to demo - nickl

Comment: These are all valid answers so if none of them helped you will have to give us more information. At what url do you see the "No devices registered"? Can you access the server from the android browser, in the emulator, at which url? What is the output you see from the tests? Where exactly did you update the SERVER_URL and SENDER_ID and what are their values? The more details you supply the less we have to stab in the dark. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 7):

Where is your tomcat server running, and what is the SERVER_URL you provided in the Android app? I had issues when I tried that demo because my tomcat was running locally, but remember that the emulator has like a "virtual router" per say so you can't access your tomcat server just using `http://localhost:8080` from your android app. You'd have to use the IP of your machine running the Tomcat server, so it'd be like `http://[tomcat-machine's ip]:8080/gcm-demo`

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be from many sources, in mine it is because I used the wrong server URL, you should stop at http://yourserveraddress.com/gcm-demo instead of .../gcm-demo/home

```
SERVER_URL = "http://yourserveraddress.com/gcm-demo"
```

Also, have you checked that the API key you used to build the WAR file is for webserver, not for appsengine (there are 2 generated when register thru Google console API) ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. I realized that I had built the files on a network at home and tried to compile the files when I was in the work network. This changed my computer's ip. I forgot to recompile my code after changing the SERVER_URL to the new ip in the CommonUtilities.java file.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to to access the localhost of the computer where your android emulator is running you have to use the 10.0.2.2  you can read more about this here:http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses